# uninstall packages in azure function

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, azure-functions

My azure function app(python) is throwing an exception: module typing has no attribute '_classVar'. A fix for this would be to uninstall the dataclasses package. How do I uninstall this package on a python azure function using pip?

If I run `pip uninstall dataclasses`, will this reflect on deployment?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python version 3.7 or greater you need to uninstall the `dataclass` library using the same `pip uninstall dataclasses`.

As The dataclasses package is a backport of the `Python 3.7` `dataclass` functionality.

Or, ***if still you want to exist `dataclasses` you can downgrade your python version to 3.6.***

For more information please refer the below links:

- **Blog**|[***AttributeError: module ‘typing’ has no attribute ‘_ClassVar’ with Tune***](https://discuss.ray.io/t/attributeerror-module-typing-has-no-attribute-classvar-with-tune/169)
- **Similar** [***GitHub Issue***](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8638#issuecomment-735529217)

Comment: I am deploying this as a python azure function. How do I run this command?

Comment: Are you using vs code for deploying ..?

Comment: Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode)

Comment: I am using vs code for deployment. How best can I uninstall dataclasses?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a lot of trouble trying to deploy azure functions from an Azure Devops pipeline with a Python 3.7 environment, so I decided to place this here as it might help someone else with the same problem.

You need to prepare the following yaml file with your respective variables.

```
    trigger:
    - {{ branch }}
    
    variables:
      # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
      azureSubscription: '{{ azureRmConnection.Id }}'
    
      # Function app name
      functionAppName: '{{ functionAppName }}'
    
      # Agent VM image name
      vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
    
      # Working Directory
      workingDirectory: '{{ workingDirectory }}'
    
    stages:
    - stage: Build
      displayName: Build stage
    
      jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    
        steps:
        - bash: |
            if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
            then
                dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
            fi
          workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
          displayName: 'Build extensions'
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: 3.6 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today
    
        - bash: |
            pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
            rm -rf ./.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dataclasses-0.6*
            rm ./.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dataclasses.py
          workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
          displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          displayName: 'Archive files'
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: zip
            archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            replaceExistingArchive: true
    
        - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          artifact: drop
    
    - stage: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy stage
      dependsOn: Build
      condition: succeeded()
    
      jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: 'development'
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
    
              steps:
              - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
                displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
                  appType: functionAppLinux
                  appName: $(functionAppName)
                  package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

These are the key lines after installing the requirements.txt. These will remove the package from the site-packages folder.

```
rm -rf ./.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dataclasses-0.6*
rm ./.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dataclasses.py
```

`pip uninstall dataclasses` will not work because you are not in the right folder.

Hope this helps!